# how to get lxml installed on 64bit windows 10 machine using python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, pip

I am trying to run a python file with requires `lxml` getting below error. mine is a company laptop with `win 10 64bit` , `python 2.7` is already installed.

> C:\Users\dgutti\Desktop\Updates>python semp_main.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "semp_main.py", line 5, in 
>       import readBuildFile as read_build   File "C:\Users\dgutti\Desktop\Updates\readBuildFile.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from lxml import etree ImportError: No module named lxml

I tried installing lxml using pip, but getting SSL error so i tried trusting hosts. BUt nothing works. Could anyone help on how to execute
 python file that uses lxml?

> C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts>pip install lxml Collecting lxml
>   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/lxml/   Retrying (Retry(total=3,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown
>   protocol (_ssl.c:726)'),)': /simple/lxml/   Retrying (Retry(total=2,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/lxml/   Retrying (Retry(total=1,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/lxml/   Retrying (Retry(total=0,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown
>   protocol (_ssl.c:726)'),)': /simple/lxml/   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/: There was a problem confirming
>   the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/lxml/ (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol
>   (_ssl.c:726)'),)) - skipping   Could not find a version that satisfies
>   the requirement lxml (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>   for lxml
>
> C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts>pip install --trusted-host
>   pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org lxml Collecting
>   lxml   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
>   redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/lxml/   Retrying (Retry(total=3,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/lxml/   Retrying (Retry(total=2,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/lxml/   Retrying (Retry(total=1,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown
>   protocol (_ssl.c:726)'),)': /simple/lxml/   Retrying (Retry(total=0,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/lxml/   Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement lxml (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for lxml
>
> C:\Program Files\Python27>python -m pip install --trusted-host
>   pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host
>   pypi.org --upgrade pip Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,
>   read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/ Retrying (Retry(total=3,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/ Retrying (Retry(total=2,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/ Retrying (Retry(total=1,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/ Retrying (Retry(total=0,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
>   out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/ Requirement already
>   up-to-date: pip in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

If your PC is behind a corporate firewall you may need to specify a proxy for `pip`. You can do so by setting the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables in your CMD window before launching `pip`:

```
set http_proxy=http://<<Proxy IP address>>:<<Proxy IP port>>
set https_proxy=http://<<Proxy IP address>>:<<Proxy IP port>>
```

Consider setting also the `no_proxy` variable to specify which networks should be reached bypassing your proxy:

```
set no_proxy=127.0.0.1,<<Other local networks>>
```